# does the filePath argument for enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource have to be a non-relative path?

Tags: enterprise-library

The MSDN documentation for this element says "The path that points to the configuration file. This attribute is required if the configuration source is a file." Ok that's fairly obvious.

I tried just setting it to  filePath="enterpriselibrary.config". The file exists in the root of my web app. But when I try to log an exception I get "The configuration file enterpriselibrary.config could not be found." Same thing if I use a relative path "~/enterpriselibrary.config".

So what's the story with this file path, does it have to be a hard path (C:
...\MyApp\enterpriselibrary.config)? Is there some documentation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in EL 5.0: http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/26760

The bug is fixed in EL 5.0 Optional Update 1. There is also a workaround on that bug page (code below). I've used the workaround successfully.

```
workaround:
code:
[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationElementType(typeof(FileConfigurationSourceElement))]
class FileConfigurationSource : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource
{

public FileConfigurationSource(string configurationFilepath)
: base(configurationFilepath)
{
}
}
class FileConfigurationSourceElement : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSourceElement
{
public override Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.IConfigurationSource CreateSource()
{
string configurationFilepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, this.FilePath);
return new FileConfigurationSource(configurationFilepath);
}
}
config:
<add name="sourceName" type="YourNamespase.FileConfigurationSource, YourAssembly" filePath ="fileName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `filePath` can be relative or absolute.  If you specify a relative path then the path is considered relative to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` directory.  As you discovered you cannot use a root-relative path (~/enterpriselibrary.config).

I'm not sure why your config file is not found; the root of your web application should be the BaseDirectory.

To debug you can check that:

```
File.Exists(
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
        "enterpriselibrary.config"))
```

returns `true`.  If it does then Enterprise Library should be able to find the file specified.